# Css Friendly Adapters stopped working

Tags: asp.net, control-adapter, css-friendly

I used the Css Friendly Adapters on a site that ran for a few years successfully and after making some changes, the adapters silently fail - but only on the server. On my local copy, it still works fine. On the server, my treeview html renders as a mess of tables instead of an unordered list like it used to. I've gone to the trouble of inserting some error logging into the source code for the Css Friendly Adapters and as far as I can tell the CSSFriendly.dll isn't being called upon at all, yet if I remove the dll, the application won't compile.

My CSSFriendlyAdapters.browser file is as follows:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.MenuAdapter" />
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.TreeViewAdapter" />
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.DetailsViewAdapter" />
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.FormViewAdapter" />
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.DataListAdapter" />
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.GridViewAdapter" />
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard"
        adapterType="CSSFriendly.WizardAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>

  <browser id="W3C_Validator" parentID="default">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="^W3C_Validator" />
    </identification>
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="browser"              value="W3C Validator" />
      <capability name="ecmaScriptVersion"    value="1.2" />
      <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCss"          value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
      <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
      <capability name="tagWriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
      <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Does anybody have any thoughts on what could be causing this problem? I'm at a loss. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in another post:

"...the simple fix is to delete the __browserCapabilitiesCompiler.compiled file from the BIN directory of the website."

See this article:  http://conficient.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/fix-for-precompiled-websites-from-vs2010-on-net-3-5-for-cssfriendly-adapters/